# How to get data from database read from another file node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have problem when I try to use data from another file in my nodejs program
the example is like this.

```
const Search = require('./model/Search');

getData = () => {
  let result = []

  Search.find({}, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      result.push = data[i].title;
    }
  });

  return result;
}
```

and I will get the result in another file

```
const coba = require('./data');

console.log(coba);
```

and I get undefined in my terminal. Can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: try like this const coba = require('./data').getData();

Comment: when i try `const coba = require('./data').getData();` and `console.log(coba)` I still get undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
getData = () => {                                                         
  let result = []                                             
  Search.find({}, (err, data) => {                                         
    if (err) {                                              
     console.log(err);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      result.push = data[i].title;
    }
    // return statement should be inside Search.find callback
    return result;
  });
}
```

Hi, your Search.find is asynchronous function as it is fetching results from DB. and you have your return statement outside that asynchronous function because of which you are getting undefined. Please find the correction in above snippet. By the way Sorry, I completely got it wrong in my first attempt to answer. Edited the same post. Cheers!

Comment: Can I directly use the data from database in another file, or should use fs first to get that?

Comment: once you write all data from database to a file, you have to use fs to read that json file